# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with C# - Identify Existing Table of Contents Object

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, tableofcontents

I'm working off a template document that has an existing Table of Contents object. I am having trouble identifying it and assigning it to a TableOfContents object programatically for further manipulation/updating.

I have examined the documentation for the TablesOfContents interface, and the only way I can see to return an object of the proper type is through the TablesOfContents.Add() function. I don't want to add a new TOC though. I just want to identify the one that already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be explained in the documentation:

"The [Document.TablesOfContents Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.tablesofcontents.aspx) returns a `TablesOfContents` collection that represents the tables of contents in the specified document."

Once you have that, "[Use TablesOfContents(index)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.tablesofcontents.aspx), where index is the index number, to return a single TableOfContents object. The index number represents the position of the table of contents in the document."

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't seem to work, or maybe I'm missing something. It returns "Non-invocable member Microsoft.Interop.Word._Document.TablesOfContents' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: C# may require brackets for the indexer, i.e. `TablesOfContents[index]`